# Google Fit REST API and Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-fit, google-fit-api

I have a game developed for me in Unity. The game pulls steps, blood pressure and glucose data. So far my developer have been able to pull health data from Apple Health Kit, but they are stuck with Google Fit. Does the Google Fit REST API work with Unity? Will I need my to create a plugin? Sorry, I have the code, but I would know what to show. I could ask my developer if that is needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a great feature to extend Google SDK to the Unity platform. The official libraries do not exist yet, but suggested workaround is to use REST API. You may start working around with Google Fit API on the official  [docs](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/get-started). You can opt to use OAuth Playground or any API platform to start with. Once you establish communication with Google Fit, try to make a call between a client and a server with the help of RESTful API in Unity.